# Strange output when trying to display an array of characters C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, ascii

## Context

I'm trying to create a Rotor struct that holds arrays of characters in a specific sequence.

## Code

Rotor

```
struct Rotor
{
public:
    char assignedRotor[26];
    void setRotor(int rotor) {
        switch(rotor) {
            case(1):
                assignedRotor = rotor1;
                break;
            case(2):
                assignedRotor = rotor2;
                break;
            case(3):
                assignedRotor = rotor3;
                break;
        };
    }
private:
    char rotor1[26] = {'E', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'L', 'G', 'D', 'Q', 'V', 'Z', 'N', 'T', 'O', 'W', 'Y', 'H', 'X', 'U', 'S', 'P', 'A', 'I', 'B', 'R', 'C', 'J'};
    char rotor2[26] = {'A', 'J', 'D', 'K', 'S', 'I', 'R', 'U', 'X', 'B', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'T', 'M', 'C', 'Q', 'G', 'Z', 'N', 'P', 'Y', 'F', 'V', 'O', 'E'};
    char rotor3[26] = {'B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'C', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'X', 'V', 'Z', 'N', 'Y', 'E', 'I', 'W', 'G', 'A', 'K', 'M', 'U', 'S', 'Q', 'O'};
};
```

Displaying rotor

```
int main() {
    Rotor rotor;
    for(int i; i < 26; i++) cout << enig.rotor2.assignedRotor[i]
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

[image: Output]

Is my "initialization" or "displaying" incorrect? Or is it both?

Comment: but you ***didn't*** set it to the second rotor?

Comment: What is `Machine`?  Where is the call to `setRotor`?  Please make a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and post text, not pictures of text.

Comment: Your loops are wrong. You should get an uninitialized variable warning by your compiler actually! `int i` will not initialize `i` so it will be some random garbage value which happens to exist at a certain memory location from before, not zero. Use `int i = 0` instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `case` statements aren't usually written with parentheses. `case 1:` works just fine.

Comment: Yeah it was because of the loops, thanks boys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++ if you are declaring any variable you have to initialize its value otherwise it will be a garbage value. In your case, you are just declaring `int i` in the loop and variable `i` will point to some garbage value. Which you can fix by initializing `i = 0` in the loop.

```
int main()
{
    Machine enig;

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        cout << enig.rotor1.assignedRotor[i] << endl;
    };

    return 0;

}
```